# Dynamically generate object with shape of cylinder segment

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is it possible to generate an object shaped like this dynamically in unity?

I need the angle of the object to be able to change from a thin sliver to a full donut-like part, so modelling each possible version would be very time-consuming and hard to use.

[image: part of cylinder]

Comment: As it stands, this question is a bit broad for the scope of this site. It'll be tough, but you may consider [programmatic mesh generation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html). This will require learning how to model polygons mathematically (e.g. How to place points along a segment of a circle). Then, it will require understanding how that translates to vertices and triangles (how to break down a shape into the triangles needed to render a mesh). Give it a shot, and if you run into specific issues programming it, then write a more specific question on this site. Good luck!

Comment: Don't think it is to broad .. it is quite clear what he wants. I did something very similar with a torus I the past https://answers.unity.com/questions/1492313/dynamically-creating-a-torus-segment-in-unity-depe.html maybe you can adopt it also for a cylinder

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically generate meshes like comments say.

However, if the angle is dynamic i.e. changes often, doing so will waste CPU time and GPU bandwidth best spent on something else. A better option, model (or generate programmatically at startup) 180° or 270° shape, and write a vertex shader to roll up or roll down the shape around center.

To keep things simple, model your shape so the cylinder axis is Z, center XY is `{0, 0}` (Z doesn’t matter), the opening of the shape is directed towards `-X`, and the shape is symmetrical around Y=0 plane. I’m talking about object’s local coordinates, you can then position/rotate the model however you want.
Here’s vertex shader code (untested):

```
float len = length( float2( position.x, position.y ) );
float newAngle = atan2( position.y, position.x ) * rollFactor;
float3 newPosition = float3( len * cos( newAngle ), len * sin( newAngle ), position.z );
output.position = UnityObjectToClipPos( newPosition );
```

This way, you only need to update a single constant variable `rollFactor` to transform your shape into any angle. If the initial shape is 270°, set the constant to 1.33334 to roll up into a full donut, 1.0 to keep it at 270°, 0.33333 to roll down to 90° like on your screenshot, etc.